# How can i send array of data from laravel blade to controller

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I have created a form and I used alpine js to add something to the array data, but I don't know how to pass it to the controller as a post method

[image: code]

Comment: Please, copy-paste the code, not an image as the image will go down in the future rendering this question unusable

Answer (score 0):

It is super important that you read the [official Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#introduction), you are not a magician, so you must get this knowledge from somewhere.

You are not sharing a controller code, so I will assume you have this one:

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('greeting', ['name' => 'James']);
});
```

If you have this on your view, it will render that name:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, {{ $name }}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```